Проблема после преобразовании из FAT32 в NFTS. Аварийная остановка
Всех приветствую. Такая проблема внешний диск ssd на 256gb решил преобразовать из FAT32 в NTFS (в программе Paragon Disk Manager 2015), чтобы мог закинуть файл более 4 gb. Посреди процесса произошло аварийное отключение и процесс был утрачен.
Как итог- файлы есть, размеры совпадают, а открываться не хотят.
Как идея, что просто перекодировка какая-то была, но чего то не хватает.

За ошибки извините,  не досмотрел.

Несите в сервис и ничего более не предпринимайте. Но... не рассчитывайте на успех. FAT32? На SSD? В 2024 году? Надо было спрашивать ДО того. Умные люди сказали бы: снимите данные с винта и просто отформатируйте, а потому верните данные назад. Время хотели сэкономить? Сэкономили.

@FoxFox, что за бред?

Сколько столетий назад появился NTFS? Уже даже самый занюханый телевизор понимает эту файловую систему.

@FoxFox, Сколько столетий назад появился NTFS? воу, полегче, компам в целом как бы и одного века еще нету. NTFS так и вовсе из 93го года(31год всего то) Уже даже самый занюханый телевизор понимает эту файловую систему не "уже" а "еще" у перехода x86/x64 с BIOS на UEFI одна наиболее заметных особенностей - зачистка по части поддержки "из коробки". там избавились и от NTFS и от прочих ФС, в пользу одной лишь FAT32.

Ржунимагу. Обычную гиперболу приняли за чистую монету. 30 лет тоже немало. Достаточно, чтоб услышать от МС и прочих: переходите на безопасную файловую систему ВОВРЕМЯ. Да, установка с помощью UEFI - действительно тот самый анахронизм, который присутствует. Но речь идёт об установке софта, то есть ни о чём. НЕ О ХРАНЕНИИ ДАННЫХ, которые критичны и важны.

@FoxFox, ну и с какой же стати ntfs безопаснее, чем fat?

Я думаю, в сети достаточно материалов на эту тему. Есть ещё и следующий этап развития файловой системы - gpt. В этом материале автора всё  прекрасно. Имея только одну копию данных, автор решил переложить проблему на "папеньку Paragon". Я такое делал, кстати. У меня срабатывало. Потому что логические диски были в идеальном порядке. Но я бы НИКОГДА не рискнул выполнять подобные операции, не сделав резерв. Впрочем, если есть резерв, никаких парагоны и не нужны. В те времена внешние винты стоили приличные бабки, а сегодня? Где резервирование?! Вот и выстрелило.


Если это возможно, отключаешь trim до подключения ssd (иначе вероятность восстановления, вероятно, снижается).
Подключаешь диск в readonly-режиме.
Делаешь посекторный образ диска (например, с помощью ddrescue в линуксе) и сохраняешь себе, желательно ещё делаешь его копию.
Дальнейшие шаги лучше делать с примонтированным образом диска, который будет меняться каждым шагом, поэтому для каждого шага лучше копировать файл образа перед монтированием. Копировать из сделанного файла образа, а не с номителя.
Берёшь Recuva и пытаешься восстановить данные с флажком "поиск неудалённых файлов". Для этого шага можно подключать образ readonly.
Запускаешь chkdsk - возможно, он что-то сделает и файлы станут доступны.
Пытаешься выполнить конвертирование в ntfs и/или fat32 (в 4 комбинациях: каждое преобразование из состояния образа - это 2, и второе преобразование после первого - это ещё 2).
Из получившейся кучи файлов выбираешь лучшее.


Файлы все в наличии. Т. е.  видны, открываются, но даже служебная информация файла .doс в не своей кодировке. В принципе такая ситуация и с архивами, изображениями, но названия их все правильные. Через пару часов могу прислать пример файла.

@Winux, нафиг мне пример файла?
